# my laptop touchpad stops working during the live demo

Tags: dual-boot, touchpad

I m completely new to all of this...

I just want to install ubuntu because it is suppose to get rid of most of the virus problems, so anyway I was following online instructions to install ubuntu alongside windows 7 these are my laptop specifications.

[image]

I tried booting with a pendrive using netbootin and other similar program but once I boot the laptop in ubuntu I click **try without installing** button and go to desktop then my mouse stops working.

What am I supposed to do or what am I doing wrong??

Also please suggest a thread for proper installation of ubuntu alongside Windows 7. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What actually happens is when you are starting a live demo of Ubuntu, it changes bios settings internally. I have tried to reset all Bios settings but the issue was still there.

To reset bios, either reinstall BIOS or update BIOS.It can be downloaded from your laptop manufacturer website. For me, it did the magic. I hope, it will work for you also.